# How to make dialogFragment width match parent?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-dialogfragment

I have this `dialog fragmentt`, and I have two problems.

> 1.How do i make the width match parent (cleanest and best solution please).
>
> 2. In the `dialog fragment` i have an editText. How do i make it pop up a soft keyboard when the dialog fragment opens?

Hope you guys can help!

Here is my dialog fragment java code:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_13g_add_comment, container, false);//The container is the rootView.

        myCognito = new MyCognito(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),getActivity().getBaseContext());

        cardClient = myCognito.getCardClient();

        bindActivity();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void bindActivity()
    {
        doneButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_comment_doneButton);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_comment_IV);

        RemoveGlideCacheAsyncTask removeGlideCacheAsyncTask = new RemoveGlideCacheAsyncTask(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().user.getUsername());
        removeGlideCacheAsyncTask.execute();


        editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_comment_ET);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                enableSubmitButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }
        });

        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_comment_IV);

        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    private void enableSubmitButton()
    {
        boolean isReady = editText.getText().toString().length() > 0;
        if(isReady)
        {
            doneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

And here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/add_comment_IV"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Add a comment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/add_comment_ET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:maxLength="140"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/green_main"
            android:id="@+id/add_comment_doneButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 19):

Open the `DialogFragment` as below

```
SampleDialogFragment sampleDialogFragment = new SampleDialogFragment();
SampleDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
SampleDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "sometag");
```

Then in the `DailogFragment` override `onStart()` method as below

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  getDialog().getWindow()
         .setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Then to show softkeyboard try this

```
((InputMethodManager) sampleedittext.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(
        sampleedittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

or you can
Create a custom style for `Dialog`

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="AppTheme" >
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

then use that style in dialog fragment

```
@Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
}

@Override public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  getDialog().getWindow()
    .setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}

SampleDialogFragment sampleDialogFragment = new SampleDialogFragment();
SampleDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "sometag");
```

Comment: if i do `SampleDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME,0); `then, my background for the dialog fragment becomes transparent.

Comment: You can set `backgroundcolor` to root view of dialog or try the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Use appcompactDialog and apply below theme :

```
 <style name="dialogFullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Below is java code sample :

```
 AppCompatDialog dialogVideoView = new AppCompatDialog(context,R.style.dialogFullScreen);
 dialogVideoView.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_video_surface);
 dialogVideoView.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom dialog box you can use:

```
Dialog dialog_guest = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

dialog_guest.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

dialog_guest.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

dialog_guest.setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);

dialog_guest.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog_guest.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

dialog_guest.show();
```

Also i think your keyboard will automatically open up. If not then use:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        yourEditText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you can add this to your `dialog style` in `style.xml`

```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

And for another ,you have to let your `EditText` requestFocus and show the keyboard,here is the code:

```
edit.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) edit.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view inside your fragment's layout with a very large height and width:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1600dp"
    android:layout_height="1600dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

and then in the `onCreateView` method of the DialogFragment add the following code:

```
if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

Tested with `ConstraintLayout` (so it should work on all types of layouts).